# Why is the flow from overhead tank merely a trickle?

Tags: plumbing

[image]

The height A is 6 ft and B is 2 feet

Answer (score 1):

The way you've drawn it, during the "limited time", the static pressure at the tap is determined by the vertical distance between the tap and the water surface in the "overhead tank" and not the "storage tank".

Outside the "limited time" the static pressure at the tap is determined by the difference in height between the tap and the water surface in the "storage tank".

Restricted flow to the tap is probably due to a blockage (or insufficient pipe diameter for length of run) somewhere in the pipework. It is possible that non-return valve NRV2 is blocked, faulty or installed incorrectly.

Comment: Hi RGBrick, thanks. Yes, the supply switches from overhead to storage automatically, and uses overhead supply as long as that lasts, I designed it for exactly that purpose. Yes, the static pressures will be as you described. And yes, I think NRV2 is the problem, but was just checking with the experts here if there was something else I was missing. So what you are saying is that the sizing of NRV is correct. Or is there a rule of thumb that one must upsize an NRV it to maintain the cross section of the piping? Also, the loop does not interfere with the total head at the tap in storage tank use.

Comment: I doubt that 1/2-inch pipe, assuming that's ID, is the problem. That's plenty big enough not to restrict water flow (see any garden hose).  The most likely candidate after the NRV being clogged or backwards is that the float valve's overflow connection to the outlet line is clogged or improperly fitted.

Comment: For sure the NRV is fitted correctly, levelled and all. Also it is not clogged as this is a very recent fitting. And the problem was noticed right off, not that it became worse over time.  Not saying is 1/2 inch pipe is good enough, what am asking is that the flow cross section of NRV is perhaps less than a 1/2 inch pipe. But thanks for confirming that the 1/2 inch ID is not the problem.

Comment: Anyhow am getting the NRV changed to a 1 inch NRV with reducers. Will post if that makes a difference.